# Shouldly and Json.NET: This passes?! JToken.Parse("{}").ShouldBe("hello");

Tags: c#, json, nunit, json.net

Can anyone explain this strange interaction between [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) (from Json.NET 4.5) and [Shouldly](http://shouldly.github.io/) 1.1.1.1?

Here's the full C# code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;  
using Shouldly;

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void this_test_passes()
    {
        JToken.Parse("{}").ShouldBe("hello");
    }
}
```

NOTE: the string `"hello"` is not special, it can be any string.

I'm guessing this has something to do with implicit casting to some type that overrides `Equals(...)` to return true for all strings, or something. But that's the best I can do, can anyone explain what is really going on here?

**EDIT: I've submitted [a patch for this issue](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/pull/66), will update again if it gets merged into master.**

**UPDATE: Issue fixed for next release... :)** https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/issues/65#issuecomment-34579229

Comment: This sounds like a bug in shouldly... surely all the explanation we need is "there's a bug in shouldly" ?

Comment: That was my first instinct, but I can't replicate this without a JToken. E.g. `new object().ShouldBe("hello")` fails at expected.

Comment: Hmmm - my apologies: actually it is NUnit and JSON.NET; in many ways, shouldly is the victim, not the perpetrator

Comment: It's true that this is a strange class, but I think Shouldly should be able to cope with this situation... I've opened an issue https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/issues/65

Comment: " Please see this question on StackOverflow for more details" - you might want to add a link to the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the generic type resolution for this gives:

```
JToken.Parse("{}").ShouldBe<JToken>("hello");
```

using the implicit conversion operator from `string` to `JToken` - so we're actually comparing two `JToken`s, not a `JToken` and a `string`.

This fails because `JToken : IEnumerable<JToken>`, referring to the sub-tokens. NUnit therefore decides to perform a sequence equality test **only**. And for both of those, there is no sub-sequence:

```
JToken x = JToken.Parse("{}");
Console.WriteLine(x.Any()); // False
JToken y = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(y.Any()); // False
```

And two empty sequences are typically considered to be equal.

For info (from metadata, not source):

```
public abstract class JToken : IJEnumerable<JToken>,
      System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JToken>, IEnumerable,
      IJsonLineInfo, ICloneable, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    // ...
    public static implicit operator JToken(string value);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, that had me scratching my head... There's probably nothing sensible Shouldly can really do to change this behaviour, other than dropping the generic type param and checking for type equality in code before attempting to cast to the type of the subject of the assertion...

Comment: Well, I've sent [a pull request with a fix for this issue](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/pull/66). It's a correct assumption that if two things are different types, they should not be considered equal.. Isn't it?

Comment: @SamSalisbury not necessarily, no; for example: `IList<int> x = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, y = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; x.ShouldBe(y);` currently passes

Comment: Hmm, that is convenient, but there's no test for that case in the Shouldly unit tests. I think this case can be supported as well though... I'll update the PR

Comment: This issue is now fixed for Shouldly version 1.1 https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/issues/65